# Django view for quiz

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am a newbie to Django, I want to make quiz app but I am stuck in the problem. I have created 3 models(Quiz, Question, Choice). I want to write a function which returns questions which have the same quiz title.

I tried this

**views.py**

```
def detail(request):
    sets = Quiz.objects.all()
    question = Question.objects.filter(sets.title)
    return render(request,'App/appdetail.html',{'question':question})
```

**models.py**

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    set = models.ForeignKey(Quiz,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_txt = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_txt

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_txt = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    boolean = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_txt
```

**Error Message**

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
def detail(request,pk):
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz,pk=pk)
    questions = quiz.question_set.all()
    return render(request,'App/appdetail.html',{'questions':questions,'quiz':quiz})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the questions with same quiz title by filtering questions on quiz foreignKey `set` in your `Question` model.

```
question = Question.objects.filter(set__title='your_quiz_title')
```

Comment: @Swapnil-Mangaonker let me know if this works for you.

Comment: hi Astik, its worked but not that way which I wanted.i have created many quizzes with a different name. I have created an index page which shows all the quiz title. after clicking that quiz title i want to show all the question which have same quiz title.

Comment: Yeah the above code will work fine. You just need to pass the quiz_title as the parameter to the method from the url.